# Hibernate lazy fetch empty after one result was empty

Tags: java, hibernate, session, many-to-many, fetch

Well hello,

I am writing a console application that is connected to a postgres database and i've come across the following problem:

```
public List<String> getCommonInterestsOfMyFriends(long personId) {

     Person personOfIntrest = session.get(Person.class, personId);
     //fetch friends from db via get Call
     int size = personOfIntrest.getFriends().size();
     int size2 = personOfIntrest.getFriendsWith().size();
     int size3 = personOfIntrest.getIntrests().size();

    Set<Tag> interests = personOfIntrest.getIntrests();

    Set<Person> allFriends = personOfIntrest.getFriendships().keySet();

    for (Person p : allFriends) {

         Set<Tag> friendsInterests = p.getIntrests();
         friendsInterests.retainAll(interests);
    } 
 }
```

A person can have interests modeled by a ManyToMany relationship with a join table. 
I call the code above several times and it works totally fine until i come across a Person that has no interests. 
After that, for every Person the "interests" Set is empty, even though the set was successfully loaded before.

To intialize the lazy association i call the getters, i also tried fetch joins

```
// fetch associated data via fetch join
    Query q = session.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p " 
                                + "LEFT JOIN FETCH p.friends "
                                + "LEFT JOIN FETCH p.friendsWith " 
                                + "LEFT JOIN FETCH p.intrests " 
                                + "WHERE p.id = :id");
    q.setParameter("id", personId);
    Person personOfIntrest = (Person) q.getSingleResult();
```

Still the same Problem.
The set of interests is successfully loaded as long as i did not query for a person that has no interests, after that the set is empty for any Person.
This is all in the same Session.

Thanks for the Help,
kind regards

Comment: It's hard to understand what happens without knowing which of the many persons invoved in this code you're talking about, which persons are linked to which other ones, and which calls you"re doing. But the code calls retainAll() on the interests of many persons, which removes interests from the set. So I'm not surprised you end up with empty sets after a while, especially if one of the persons has no interest.

Comment: Yes, the Problem is the first call of getIntrests() in line 9.  
Let me maybe give you an example. 
I query for Person with ID 9, this Person has a relating column in the join table, set intrests is loaded, everything's fine. 
Then i query for Person with ID 10 which has no intrests, so the set is empty, also fine. 
Now in the same session, if i query for person 9 again, set of intrests is now empty, same for every person after that, whether they actually have intrests or not. 
This is all before the intersection part, i see why this might be confusing, i should maybe remove that part

Comment: The part that you removed is most probably the cause of your problem. The method is supposed to return interests common to several persons, but it modifies the interests of all the friends of the found person. Why do you modify those sets? Don't believe it's a bug in Hibernate. it's a bug in your code.

Comment: I never said this is a Hibernate bug, i was just asking what could be the problem. 
Found the error though, I thought since the changes on the set are not persisted i shouldn't worry, but i ended up manipulating the java object in the same session, somehow i thought it would be loaded again from the database when calling the getters or join fetch query, but this is not the case. 
I deep copied the Set before calling retainAll() and now it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering in future:

I ended up manipulating the friends interests by calling `friendsInterests.retainAll(interests);` on the Set. Since this change was not persisted i didn't think it was a big deal.

I made the mistake of thinking that calling the persisted objects getter or the query again would reload the object from the database, even in the same session. This is not the case!

I deep copied the Set before the call and know everything works as expected:

```
for (Person p : allFriends) {

        Set<Tag> friendsInterests = p.getIntrests();
        Set<Tag> fiCopy = new HashSet<Tag>();
        fiCopy.addAll(friendsInterests);

        fiCopy.retainAll(interests);
}
```